# SwiftUI Custom Tab Bar Navigation: Return to Root View when icon tabbed

Tags: swiftui

I followed this tutorial to create a custom tab bar in my SwiftUI app: https://blckbirds.com/post/custom-tab-bar-in-swiftui/

I would like to achieve that when you tab an icon you will always be moved to the "RootView" of the NavigationView within that tab's view. E.g, on HomeView I have a NavigationView with nested views. So when you navigate to DetailView1 -> DetailView2 and then tab on the Home icon again you will go back to the initial view.

For the custom navigation I have a ViewRouter.swift

```
ViewRouter.swift

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .home
}

enum Page {
    case home
    case liked
    case add
    case records
    case user
}
```

In my ContentView I have

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                switch viewRouter.currentPage {
                case .home:
                    HomeView()
                case .liked:
                    LikedView()
                case .add:
                    AddView()
                case .records:
                    RecordsView()
                case .user:
                    UserView()
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .home, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "homekit", tabName: "Home")
                    TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .liked, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "heart", tabName: "Liked")
                    TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .records, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "waveform", tabName: "Records")
                    TabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .user, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "person.crop.circle", tabName: "Account")
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/8)
                .background(Color("TabBarBackground"))
                .shadow(radius: 2)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarIcon: View {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    var assignedPage: Page
    
    let width, height: CGFloat
    let systemIconName, tabName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: systemIconName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            Text(tabName)
                .font(.footnote)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, -4)
        .onTapGesture {
            viewRouter.currentPage = assignedPage
        }
        .foregroundColor(viewRouter.currentPage == assignedPage ? Color("TabBarHighlight") : .gray)
    }
}
```

And then in my HomeView as example a NavigationView with multiple levels. Navigation is working fine, also when you're on another tab and tab on Home you always land on the first view of this navigation stack which is perfect. So I want to achieve the same thing when you're inside Home's NavigationView, kind of like resetting the NavigationStack.

Any ideas?

Comment: So your navigation stack is working as expected, but when you're at Home you want to go to where?

Comment: Say I have a NavigationView on HomeView with several levels. I go to NavigationLink1, then to NavigationLink2, and then when I tab the tab bar icon again it should bring me back to the root HomeView again, so at the beginning of the navigation